# $H^s$ boundedness and $L^2$ convergence imply limit is $H^s$ bounded

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

In a math text I'm reading, I've come across the following. We have a sequence
$$ \{u_n\} \subset H^s(\mathbb{R}), \qquad s \geq 4$$
and we know that 
$$ \| u_n \|_{H^s} \leq C \qquad \text{uniformly} $$
$$ u_n \to u \qquad \text{ in} \qquad L^2.$$
The authors then say that it follows from Fatou's lemma that the limit $u$ is in $H^s$. I'm having trouble seeing why.

I can see that, moving to the frequency side, Fatou's lemma says
$$ \int \langle \xi \rangle^{2s} \liminf \hat{u}_n^2 d \xi \leq \liminf \int  \langle \xi \rangle^{2s}  \hat{u}_n^2 d \xi \leq C, $$
but I don't see that 
$$ \| u\|^2_{H^s} = \int \langle \xi \rangle^{2s}  \hat{u}^2 d \xi \overset{??}{\lesssim} \int \langle \xi \rangle^{2s} \liminf \hat{u}_n^2 d \xi $$
which is what I would need to close the argument this way.

Is there another approach? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $u \mapsto \hat u$ is an isometry, we have $\hat u_n \to \hat u$ in $L^2$. Taking a subsequence if necessary, we have $\hat u^2_n \to \hat u^2$ almost everywhere. Thus by Fatou's lemma, 
$$\int |\xi|^{2s} \hat u^2 d\xi = \int \liminf_{n\to \infty}\left( |\xi|^{2s}  \hat{u_n}^2\right) d \xi \le \liminf_{n\to \infty} \int |\xi|^{2s} \hat{u}_n^2 d \xi<\infty$$